# How can I add a cell's contents to another cell and then automatically delete the contents of the original cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Title kind of explains itself. I am trying to set up a way for me to input a number into one cell, have it add to whatever number is in another cell, and then clear that first cell ready for me to do it all over again.
For example, I have 10 in B1, I input 3 in A1, B1 updates to 13, and A1 clears and is now empty. I saw something similar using the following script code, but I was not able to get it to work. I kept getting an error "#NUM!". I am using Google Sheets, but if Excel would work better I do have access.

Here is the code I tried,

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    var below = e.range.offset(1, 0);
    below.setValue(Number(e.value) + Number(below.getValue()));
    e.range.clear();
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var {range, value} = e;
  var r = range.offset(0, 1);
  r.setValue(Number(value) + Number(r.getValue())); // I think Number(r.getValue()) can be modified to r.getValue()
  range.clearContent();
}
```

- In this script, the process of `For example, I have 10 in B1, I input 3 in A1, B1 updates to 13, and A1 clears and is now empty.` can be achieved.
- When you want to restrict the sheet name and the range, you can reflect them to above script by modifying.